# Eager loading including navigational property of derived class

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, ef-code-first

Sample class structure

```
class Order
{
    public int Id { get; set; }     
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    public List<OrderDetail> Details { get; set; }
}

class OrderDetail
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Qty { get; set; }

    public Item Item { get; set; }
}

class Item
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

class ElectronicItem : Item
{
    public MoreDetail Detail { get; set; }
}

class MoreDetail
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string SomeData { get; set; }
}
```

In order to populate order object with all navigational properties, I wrote

```
context.Orders.Include("Details").Include("Details.Item")
```

I also want to load MoreDetail object, hence I tried

```
context.Orders.Include("Details").Include("Details.Item.Detail")
```

It didn't work. How to load complete Order object?

Answer (score 1):

It is currently not possible but it is feature requested by community on [User DataVoice](http://data.uservoice.com/forums/72025-entity-framework-feature-suggestions/suggestions/1249289-include-property-of-derived-classes) as you already found. There is also related bug on [MS Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/594289/in-entity-framework-there-should-be-a-way-to-eager-load-include-navigation-properties-of-a-derived-class).

You simply cannot eager load navigation properties of derived types but you can load them with separate query:

```
var moreDetails = context.MoreDetails;
```

EF should automatically fix your navigation properties. If you use filtering on orders in your original query you must apply that filter in more details query as well:

```
var moreDetails = cotnext.MoreDetials.Where(m => m.Item.Order ....);
```